# Training / using OpenAI GPT-3 for translations

Tags: nlp, translate, openai-api, machine-translation, gpt-3

I'm trying to use OpenAI for translation of my products descriptions from one language to some other languages (EN, DE, CZ, SK, HU, PL, SI...). The translations, especially to SK/CZ/HU/PL languages are (mainly gramatically) quite bad (using `text-davinci-003` model). I've got an idea - I already have a few thousands of similar products fully translated into all of these languages by professional translators. Is it possible to use those existing correct translations to train GPT-3 and then use this model to translate new texts? Has anybody already tried something similar?

Comment: A few 1000 is prob a too small data set to create proper output.

Comment: "Has anybody already tried something similar?" is not a good fit for this site. Please see [help/on-topic]

Comment: Questions related to [tag:machine-learning] and related, should be about implementation. Considering this, try to add a [mcve]. If you are looking help about concepts and methodology your question might belong to [ai.se], [datascience.se], [stats.se] or [computerscience.se].

Comment: https://reddit.com/r/machinetranslation could be a better fit for this type of open-ended question.